# how to handle with python selenium chrome webdriver stuck when loading

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

All, I'm working on analyzing my instagram followers and to do it I'm using selenium in python.
I'm using the code attached below simply to scroll the window that appears when I click on "followers". (How is that window technically called? dialogue box?)
The code works perfect until, as you can see in my attached screenshot, chrome gets stuck and that window doesn't allow to scroll down anymore.

Code:

```
    num_current_users_found = 0
    individual_user_class_when_scrolling  = 'NroHT'
    time.sleep(5)
    while (num_current_users_found / tot_actual_num_of_users *100) < 99:
        try:            
            visible_individual_users = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(individual_user_class_when_scrolling)
            print("scrolling to the bottom...    len(visible_individual_users) = ",str(len(visible_individual_users)), "  vs. expected total users = ", str(tot_actual_num_of_users))
            pre_scroll_num_of_visible_users = len(visible_individual_users)         
            last_visible_user_elem = visible_individual_users[-1]
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(last_visible_user_elem)
            actions.perform()
            random_sleep(0,2)
            last_visible_user_elem.location_once_scrolled_into_view
            visible_individual_users = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(individual_user_class_when_scrolling)
            num_current_users_found = len(visible_individual_users)

            if num_current_users_found == pre_scroll_num_of_visible_users:
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            print("can't scroll anymore")
```

How can I handle chrome, without closing that window with all my followers and push the scroll all the way to the bottom?

[image]

Comment: If in each runtime, there more Instagram followers to be presented and it's loading forever on the scroll, then it's probably a bug on Instagram or some internet connection problem (less common). There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: to be honest, I was expecting a more helpful answer...

Comment: So go and report a bug to Instagram. Good luck.

Comment: could it be that using a different browser like Firefox would fix the problem?

Comment: Yep. Test it manually on IE and FireFox first. Unlikely it's a selenium issue.